# Linux shell script: How to match substring with regex

Tags: regex, linux, shell, substring

How can I get all "clid's" which has the "client_type=0"? The pipe char "|" seperates each client info. The text, which I have is just one line:

> clid=2 cid=3346 client_database_id=5153 client_nickname=xLukas\s\p\sLukas client_type=0|clid=3 cid=3346 client_database_id=1 client_nickname=powered\sby\sMirWayne.DE
>   client_type=1|clid=4 cid=3346 client_database_id=9661
>   client_nickname=Number\sone client_type=0|clid=5 cid=3469
>   client_database_id=1 client_nickname=powered\sby\sMirWayne
>   client_type=1|clid=6 cid=1716 client_database_id=1
>   client_nickname=FG\sBot client_type=1|clid=7 cid=3469
>   client_database_id=9661 client_nickname=Number\stwo
>   client_type=0|clid=8 cid=1762 client_database_id=4351
>   client_nickname=pr0zkillz1x\pTobi client_type=0|clid=9 cid=1764
>   client_database_id=5160 client_nickname=xL1mited\s/\sMax
>   client_type=0|clid=10 cid=1716 client_database_id=9704
>   client_nickname=Sebi client_type=0|clid=13 cid=3346
>   client_database_id=4336 client_nickname=checker284\s\p\sSebbo
>   client_type=0|clid=19 cid=1762 client_database_id=9312
>   client_nickname=pr0skillz1x\pDanie client_type=0|clid=30 cid=3346
>   client_database_id=9697 client_nickname=TeamSpeakUser
>   client_type=0|clid=33 cid=1716 client_database_id=1
>   client_nickname=serveradmin client_type=1

I need alle clid's, which has the client_type=0 in an extra line. For example like that:

```
    clid=2
    clid=3
    clid=4
    clid=5
    ...
```

My current solution is not working:

```
    cat clientlist.txt | grep -Eo "clid=[0-9]+[\d\D]*client_type=0" | grep -Eo "clid=[0-9]+"
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: `cat` a file into grep? Surely you jest! `grep ... clientlist.txt | ...` saves about a billion CPU cycles per invocation.

Comment: What's better? I would use each working solution, but currently I have no.

Comment: It's better to avoid a useless cat and a useless pipe. You don't drive with the brakes engaged, or do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The pipe char "|" seperates each client info.

Making use of this information, you can say:

```
tr '|' '\n' < clientlist.txt | grep -Po 'clid=\d+(?=.*client_type=0)'
```

For your input, it'd result in:

```
clid=2
clid=4
clid=7
clid=8
clid=9
clid=10
clid=13
clid=19
clid=30
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
tr '|' '\n' < file | sed -n '/client_type=0/s/\(clid=[0-9]*\).*$/\1/p'
clid=2
clid=4
clid=7
clid=8
clid=9
clid=10
clid=13
clid=19
clid=30
```

Comment: close, but not quite - you need to handle the delimiter, so the correct version is `sed -n -e 's/|/\n/' -e '/client_type=0/s/\(clid=[0-9]*\).*$/\1/p'`

Comment: @OliverMatthews: Thanks I updated, I thought there are new lines after pipe in input file.

Comment: I started making use of `grep` more often after looking at your posts, you seem to have abandoned it!

Comment: np. Out of curiousity, why tr rather than extra parameters to sed?

Comment: @devnull: lol :) not intentionally. Somehow I thought sed is better for this but your grep is pretty kool one too.

Comment: @OliverMatthews: That sed actually didn't work for me because of `-n` presence.

Comment: odd. Works on my machine (sed 4.2.2)

Comment: Oh ok probably because of my older sed version on OSX

Comment: Another solution:

        cat x | tr "|" "\n" | grep "client_type=0" | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d "=" -f2

Thanks to all!

Comment: @user2966991: Yes that will also work but requires multiple piped commands.